# Simple password-protection for React app on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, authentication, heroku, password-protection

I have a simple React app, created with create-react-app, that I'd like to deploy to Heroku (or somewhere easy) and password-protect. The protection can be really simple—just a single password is fine.

I started looking into HTTP basic auth but didn't find an easy answer. The closest I found was in [this post](https://blog.snajdr.de/adding-password-protection-to-zero-configuration-webpack-react-app-1bd3fc976996), but (a) I don't love the idea of having to eject my app, and (b) I couldn't get it working. I was hoping I could find a Heroku plugin, but no luck there either.

It wouldn't be too hard to write a component that wraps my app and requests a password before showing it. The problem is that it executes client-side. I want to store the correct password server-side (or a hash thereof), and have the app send password attempts up to the server.

Since create-react-app operates on top of Node, I'm hoping there's an easy way to tell it to execute and store certain things on the server, but maybe I'm wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: By way of clarification: Back in the Apache/PHP days, I'd just tweak my httpd config to enable basic auth, and regardless of what my app was doing it wouldn't load until a user got through a password prompt. I basically just want to do that in a Heroku/React world.

Comment: Could you provide informations about how your app is running on Heroku? Did you use `serve` or some other static server?

Comment: Do you have a backend? Do you use a database? Will the content change in the future? Will the password change in the future? Should the content be simply hidden or also protected?

Answer (score 6):

This create-react-app buildpack seems to support http basic auth:

https://github.com/substantial/create-react-app-buildpack

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/substantial/heroku-buildpack-static

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming your intentions are wanting to protect the config vars in heroku so other people cannot access you database with your credentials.

The way I password protected my deployment to heroku, is to make a keys_prod.js file containing the Heroku config vars of my mLab database in my backend using express and mongoDB:

keys_prod.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI,
  secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET_OR_KEY
};
```

keys.js file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./keys_prod');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./keys_dev');
}
```

in my server.js file I added:

```
// DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// Server static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

This allows you to request the config vars you filled in heroku without including it in your repo.

Comment: I think you're thinking of something different—this is for end users. When someone opens my app in her browser, I want a password prompt before she's allowed to use it. Basically a really simple login.

Comment: Oh my bad, thought your question was related to protect your credentials in your Heroku build. I do not have simple solution, but have you looked into passport.js and json webtoken? You need some boilerplate to get it working but in the end you can make your express routes private by using: `router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {`

Basically by filling login info you providing the user with a webtoken to let them access the page for a predetermined length of time. If they are inactive for a while it will automatically expire the session.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Node in backend you can use [Passport Basic Auth](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/basic-digest/)

```
app.get('*', passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(`${__dirname}/../build/index.html`))
})
```

Every time you access the page in browser, a popup will appear, asking you username and password.

Comment: Is this doable within the confines of create-react-app or does it require me to eject and configure further?

Comment: Does not require ejecting