# Setting up http basic auth on heroku and react app

Tags: reactjs, authentication, heroku, basic-authentication

as mentioned in the the title I want to set up a react app with http basic auth or something similar that prevents my website to be public. I've seen that there the wwwhisper plugin on heroku that would do exactly that. But as far as I know this only works with rack and nodejs. Do you have any suggestions about this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990251/simple-password-protection-for-react-app-on-heroku

Comment: wwwhisper add-on mentioned in your question was recently updated to support any language and framework on Heroku. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/wwwhisper#enabling-the-wwwhisper-buildpack